# Confirmation of maximization problem

Tags: calculus, optimization

Hey all I am working on a problem, and my numbers are coming out not so nice so I think It is possible that I am making a mistake and if so Id be really interested in learning how to do it correctly.

The question is to find the max and min values of $f(x,y)=5x-7y+4xy-7x^2+4y^2$ defined in the unit square ($ 0 \le x \le 1$ $,0 \le y \le 1 $)

What I have done.

First, I said we can consider the critical points that are in the interior of the square,

so by setting partials to zero,

$$ f_x=5+4y-14x=0$$

$$f_y=4x+8y-7=0$$

solving by row reduction to get $x=\frac{17}{32}$ and $y=\frac{39}{64}$ with corresponding value from calculator to be $f(x,y)= \frac{-103}{128}$

But now I know I must consider the boundaries and such, that is

$$l_1: g_1(y)=f(0,y)=-7y+4y^2$$

$$l_2: g_2(x)=f(x,1)=9x-7x^2-3$$

$$l_3: g_3(y)=f(1,y)=4y^2-3y-2$$

$$l_4:g_4(x)=f(x,0)=5x-7x^2$$

Which I am a bit uncertian but I beleive I now have to take those, set their first deravatives equal to 0 and solve, then plug in if it is within the unit square and see what f(x,y) gives, that is for example,

on $l_1$ , the only critical y is $y=7/8$ ,

on $l_2$ , we solve $-14x+9=0$ , $x=9/14$ and evaluate $f(9/14,1)$ and compare to the others. I guess this is to be repeated for all lines and possibly the corners.

I am just not sure if it is right, if I am missing some crucial or not? Or is it good so far? Any suggestions or comments please. Even a check of arithmetic would be very appreciated.

Update:

I calculated the critical points for on the lines as follows

for $$ l_1 :f(0,7/8)=-49/16$$

$$l_2: f(9/14,1)=39/14$$

$$l_3: f(1, 3/8)= -41/16$$

$$ l_4 :f(5/14,0)=25/28$$

Corners,

$f(0,0)=0$,
$f(0,1)=-3$,
$f(1,0)=-2$,
$f(1,1)=-1$

Now , if my arithmetic and such is correct ( which I am positive on) is all that is left is to compare all the values?

Thanks all!

Comment: That looks right to me, although I would say "*definitely* check the corners."

Comment: @RoryDaulton Thanks I will do so, does the arithmetic look correct to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That strategy looks right to me, although I would say "*definitely* check the corners."

Regarding your work:

The interior critical point looks right, although I think that is a saddle point, not an extremum.

The critical point on $l_1$ is $y=\frac 78$, not $y=\frac 74$, so you do need to consider the point $(0,\frac 78)$.

Line $l_2$ looks right.

---

(Regarding the current, edited question)

If you are sure of your arithmetic, and if you are just looking for the *absolute* (global) maximum and minimum, then you can indeed just choose the largest and smallest function values in your list. I recommend you check your answers with a 3D plot using WolframAlpha ([maximum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=maximum+of+5x-7y%2B4xy-7x%5E2%2B4y%5E2+for+0%3Cx%3C1%2C0%3Cy%3C1), [minimum](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimum+of+5x-7y%2B4xy-7x%5E2%2B4y%5E2+for+0%3Cx%3C1%2C0%3Cy%3C1)) or something similar.

If you are also looking for relative (local) extrema, you would need more work. For example, check to see which kind of critical point each point is (saddle point in the interior, inflection point in the lines, as well as maximum or minimum).

In the more general case you would also need to check for the possibility that there is no absolute maximum or minimum: the function may go to infinity. In this question that is not a concern since you are examining a continuous function in a closed and bounded region, which guarantees absolute maximum and minimum.

Comment: Thanks, so are you saying in fact the interior does not have a max or min even?

Comment: @PersonaA: Yes, that is correct. A quick look at a [WolframAlpha plot](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=critical+points+of+5x-7y%2B4xy-7x%5E2%2B4y%5E2+for+0%3Cx%3C1%2C0%3Cy%3C1) confirms that.

Comment: Thanks, I am going to work on it more and see what I can do. I will than update it and if your not to busy maybe you could take a look

Comment: @PersonaA: I checked your updated question and updated my answer appropriately.